# Wireless is not working in my system?

Tags: wireless

I have a [HP pavilion 15-e057ej Laptop.](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareCategory?cc=il&dlc=en&lc=en&product=5399467&)

In ubuntu 12.04.04 64-bit the wireless network worked fine.

After I install fresh 14.04 64-bit, wireless isn't working - it's not enable.

What can I do?

Here's some more information:

At both versions of ubuntu: 12.04.04, 14.04 the light of the WiFi button is orange, mean it close. at 12.04.04 the wireless working fine and enable. 
At 14.04 it not working and the WiFi is not enable. 
At both version of ubuntu 12.04.04 and 14.04 the button to switch the WiFi on - turn the light to blue, is not doing anything.

- [`rfkill list`](http://pastebin.com/aeXy64aJ)
- [`sudo lshw -class network`](http://pastebin.com/CXAxAixT)
- [`sudo lspci -nn`](http://pastebin.com/7wFcwevF)
- [`cat /var/log/dmesg`](http://pastebin.com/EZhgr5N8)
- [`cat /var/log/udev`](http://pastebin.com/wB5X70uq)
- [`tail -f /var/log/kern.log`](http://pastebin.com/A2TJ7QTv)
- [Script - wireless-info.txt](http://pastebin.com/kH3xELvS)

use script from [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos):

Comment: Could you move those results to http://paste.ubuntu.com/. 
You could include short ones in the question may be better like `sudo lshw -class network`

Comment: I added as a commands. I don't use a past.ubuntu.com because it don't show a very long test. I hope you will vote up for this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I install again Ubuntu 12.04.03, the driver of the wireless card is working there.
I force the Ubuntu to upgrade to 14.04. that way the driver was stay on my system.
with this command found at [this link](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/04/upgrade-ubuntu-14-04-12-04) 
`sudo update-manager -d`

After a while, the Ubuntu upgrade with my wireless driver.

Comment: I think the culprit was a missing `linux-firmware-nonfree` package which I believe is needed for the Broadcom Wi-Fi adapter on these HP laptops. `sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree` may help some in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Your `rfkill list` command is shows `hard blocked: yes`.

That means that your wireless card is disabled. It could be that there is a switch at your laptop to enable/disable wireless. Mine has it. With `rfkill` you can just unlock a software block not a hardware switch.

It could also be that in BIOS your wireless card is disabled. Boot your machine in BIOS and check if something is disabled there.

Comment: At Ubuntu 12.04.04 the light for wireless is organ that mean close, and the wireless is working. At the 14.04 it has the same orange light for wireless. But it not working. there button for swiching the wireless on (turn the light to blue light) it not working for both ubuntu. 12.04.04 and 14.04. At the bios the wireless is enable at the same imahes. (12.04 and 14.04)

Comment: can you add the ouput of `tail -f /var/log/kern.log` when switching the button on?

Comment: Ok. I will add it when I will be at home

Comment: I add the information. I hope it help.