# What happens if you choose pci=off at the LiveCD prompt?

Tags: 14.04, ubuntu-drivers

When at the Grub screen for the Ubuntu Live CD you can choose options (by pressing <kbd>F6</kbd>) and select an option called `pci=off`.

What does that mean? How will it change how Ubuntu boots?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Linux BootPrompt Howto](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/BootPrompt-HOWTO.html):

**pci=off:**

> Using this option disables all PCI bus probing. Any device drivers
>   that make use of PCI functions to find and initialize hardware will
>   most likely fail to work.

Comment: Thank you. If I install Ubuntu with that option, I want it will recognized my wireless card. How I do it?

Comment: The default is that probing takes place in the PCI BIOS and I would let it so, that all devices are recogized. So don't use the `pci=off` boot option and your wireless card will be recognized.

Comment: But I can't. If i don‘t use this option, the Ubuntu 14.04 will not load (the live image). I need a solution after installation.

Comment: @Tal it's ok to boot the live image this way. This is just the boot option for the live system, not for the installation afterwards.

Comment: Ok. Then if I install Ubuntu that way and then it not recognize the wireless card, I need other solution?

Comment: Not connected, disabled, broken or not recognized by the BIOS, can be many faults. In the installed system, when you type `lspci` in the terminal and there is a entry starting with `Network controller: blah blah Wireless blah blah`, and `iwconfig` shows the wireless card, then your card is recognized and running.

Comment: I have other question with all the information. You mind to look at it?

Comment: If your have another question, please ask them here with a new question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask

Comment: Already have. Please look at <a href=" http://askubuntu.com/q/485349/19949 ">it</a>. Thanks for your time.